# Why Java regex pattern "[abc]{3}" matches to abc when input string is abccabaaaccbbbc

Tags: java, regex

While following oracle tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html.

Found the following command line program http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/examples/RegexTestHarness.java output :

Enter your regex: **[abc]{3}**

Enter input string to search: **abccabaaaccbbbc**

I found the text "abc" starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.

I found the text "cab" starting at index 3 and ending at index 6.

I found the text "aaa" starting at index 6 and ending at index 9.

I found the text "ccb" starting at index 9 and ending at index 12.

I found the text "bbc" starting at index 12 and ending at index 15.

My expectation is that pattern **[abc]{3}** means either *a*, either *b* or either *c* *three times* but it is matching *abc* as a whole why?

Comment: It sound like what you want instead is the regex (aaa)|(bbb)|(ccc)

Comment: it chooses an item from the give list and the it repeats the pattern exactly three times.

Comment: @antlersoft: If I were you I copy my the comment to an answer with a little bit more info, so that you can get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you're looking for would be:

```
a{3}|b{3}|c{3}
```

Your pattern means - match a string of length `3`, containing any of the characters `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Also, as @Tim pointed out in comments, this can be simplified to:

```
([abc])\1\1
```

The `([abc])` matches a single character, and captures it in group 1. Then `\1\1` says, repeat the same character twice.

Comment: I would prefer `([abc])\1\1` - less repetition.

Comment: `aaa|bbb|ccc` is even better - it is shorter by three characters than the original expression, and it requires virtually zero knowledge of regex, unlike the alternative with two backreferences.

Answer (score 2):

I think your expectation ("either a, either b or either c *three times*") is that once one character has been matched (the initial `a`), the next two characters must also be `a`, but to get that behavior you would have to use backreferences, like `([abc])\\1{2}`. Instead, what `[abc]{3}` means is simply `[abc][abc][abc]`.

(There are simpler ways of writing it, like `aaa|bbb|ccc`, but I used backreferences to follow your idea that somehow the later matches should reflect what the earlier character class matched. Backreferences do that.)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern means any of the characters `a`, `b`, or `c` appearing in any sequential order three times. `abc` is a string that matches that pattern.